# add to cart in tierprices.phtml

Tags: addtocart, tierprice

i have this line of code

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mb_change_input_value_<?php echo $_price['price_qty'] ?>() {
            document.getElementById('qty').value = <?php echo $_price['price_qty'] ?>;
        }
    </script>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart-mini" onMouseOver="mb_change_input_value_<?php echo $_price['price_qty'] ?>()" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Kaufen') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

for a Add To Cart Button in tierprices.phtml an it works fine in **product** view but not in category **list** view

Hope Someone can help me, that this work also in list view

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart-mini" onMouseOver="mb_change_input_value_<?php echo $_price['price_qty'] ?>()" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Kaufen') ?></span></span></button>
```

With

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onMouseOver="mb_change_input_value_<?php echo $_price['price_qty'] ?>()" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')">
  <span>
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Kaufen') ?></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have try this before...but dont work with Qty Increments.